# How to change the color of the column in grid based on selection of a row and some condition check

Tags: gridview, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

> I am trying to change the color of the column based on selection.Here is what I have tried so far.

```
var selectionmodel = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel');
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
storeId:'simpsonsStore',
fields:['name', 'email', 'change'],
data:{'items':[
    { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "change":100  },
    { 'name': 'Bart', "email":"bart@simpsons.com", "change":-20  },
    { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com",  "change":100   },
    { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "change":-20  }
]},
proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'items'
    }
}
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
id : 'sgrid',
title: 'Simpsons',
store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
selModel:selectionmodel,
columns: [
    { header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
    { header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
    { header: 'Change', dataIndex: 'change', tdCls: 'x-change-cell' }//
],
height: 200,
width: 400,
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
listeners:{
    selectionchange: function( thisobj, selected, eOpts ){

        var store = Ext.getStore('simpsonsStore');
        var grid = Ext.getCmp('sgrid');
        var selected = grid.getSelectionModel();
        var count = store.getCount();
        var items=[];
     //   grid.getView.removeCls("price-fall");
        for(i=0;i<count;i++){
            if(selected.isSelected(i)){
                items.push({ 
                                "change"      : store.getAt(i).data.change
                            });
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){
            for(j=i+1;j<items.length;j++){
                if(items[i].change == items[j].change){
                         grid.getView().addRowCls( i, "price-fall" ); 
                         grid.getView().addRowCls( j, "price-fall" );
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
});
```

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tPB8Z/1465/)**

**What I am trying to do :**

> Here I want to change the color of the column **'change'** based on whether it is same or not.If it is same then the color should be **green**,otherwise it should be **red**.

**My Issue**

> I am able to change the color of the column, but getting messed with selection.The cls should also be removed on deselection.Is this approach correct,or is their any other way to achieve this? Any help is aprreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're approach is quite good, and you're almost there. You only seem a bit confused about how to work with records (Model).

Just use this function as your `selectionchange` handler, and that will work:

```
// selected is an array of models (remember you have multiple selection enabled
// in you grid)
function(selModel, selected){
    var grid = Ext.getCmp('sgrid'),
        store = grid.getStore(),
        view = grid.getView(),

        selectedChanges = {},

        sameCls = 'change-same',
        diffCls = 'change-diff';

    // build a map of change values that will be considered as "same"
    Ext.each(selected, function(record) {
        selectedChanges[record.get('change')] = true;
    });

    // loops through all records and update their css class according to their
    // change value
    store.each(function(record) {

        // isn't that more expressive that accessing it through the store's item?
        var change = record.get('change');

        if (selectedChanges[change]) {
            // addRowCls can accept model as its first arg
            view.addRowCls(record, sameCls);
            view.removeRowCls(record, diffCls);
        } else {
            view.removeRowCls(record, sameCls);
            view.addRowCls(record, diffCls);
        }
    });
}
```

You may also want to add CSS rules for rows with class `.x-grid-row-selected` in order for your color markers to appear in selected row(s) as well.

Comment: Thanks rixo.This approach by building map is really helpful.